# Count all and count the records that meet a clause in a single query

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-database

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID | NetAmount | PaymentAmount
1    2.99        1.99
2    2.99        2.99
```

I wish to count all the records in the table and then divide that number with the count of records where NetAmount-PaymentAmount > 0. How can I achieve this?

(The result in this case would be 1/2 => 0.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way uses `avg()`:

```
select avg(case when netamount > paymentamount then 1.0 else 0.0 end) as ratio
from t;
```

Comment: Works, thank you. I was trying with a having clause and hit a brick wall.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 1.0 *
       COUNT(*) /
       COUNT(CASE WHEN NetAmount > PaymentAmount THEN 1 END)
FROM yourdata
```

The `1.0 *` part will ensure that you get a decimal result with 1 digit after 0.

Answer (score 0):

Using `IIF` condition:

```
SELECT AVG(IIF(NetAmount > PaymentAmount, 1.0, 0.0)) as Result
FROM tableName;
```